# Cannot call setContentView using runOnUiThread?

Tags: java, android

Is there a reason I cannot do this inside of a thread? I'm still getting a "Cannot create a handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()".

```
_currentActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        _currentActivity.setContentView(_nextScreen);
    }
});
```

Comment: add some more code.. the code that surrounds this `runOnUiThread`

Comment: Why are you trying to do this anyway? seems like a bad idea to me...

Comment: This was executed a few functions deep from a thread and, although I still don't understand why this didn't work, the new implementation I decided on uses something similar to this and works. I would post more code but there's quite a bit before it runs the code I posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can not update `UI`works on a non `UI` thread.

If you are looking to update the `UI` to the user, you must need to implement `Handler` or either `UI` thread.